# POST to writing a file - php (more than one data post)

Tags: php, post, fwrite

how would i get the above to write? ive been able to write each post when doing them one at a time, but isn't there a way to write them to the file without having to do new `$shapeType` entries followed by separate `fwrites` over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_POST['shapeType, triangleSide1, triangleSide2'];
```

This is not valid PHP. You'll have to concat a string like `$_POST['shapeType'] . ', ' . $_POST['triangleSide1'] . ', ' . $_POST['triangleSide2']` and write that to the file.

Comment: sure it's valid PHP. There's nothing in the HTML specs that says a field name can't be `<input name="a,b,c" />`. But yes, this is most likely supposed to be 3 separate $_POST references, not just this one.

Comment: ID and name parameters may not contain spaces. But my main trigger was the level of questions by the user to be honest..

Comment: where does it say they can't have spaces? http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute  "Any non-empty name for name is allowed".

Comment: Yeah, the HTML5 spec is lacking severly at that point. HTML4 forbids it (again, given the posters apparent level of knowledge, that's what he's using). Given that name is still used as an identifier in browsers, it should follow the same rules as ID attributes. The fact that they want to allow names like '...' is just plain stupid.

Comment: names have NEVER been an identity for DOM purposes. they're purely for form submission in key=value format. If they were an ID equivalent, then they'd have to be unique across the entirety of the DOM. Nothing says you can't have multiple separate forms using the SAME name attributes in each form.